# how to view the job in text in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

Ex: for store procedure we use sp_helptext .is there any keyword for viewing jobs in text in sql server 2005

regards
kumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For stuff like this where I know how to do something in Management Studio but aren't sure of the way to do it by code I sometimes start a profiler trace then perform the action in Management Studio to see what that is doing. Doing that on my system indicates that the following might help.

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobstep @job_name = 'Your job name'
```

If you look at the definition of that it seems to use `msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps`

Answer (score 3):

You can query the various tables in msdb database to get the list of the jobs and their details.

For example

```
select * from msbdb.dbo.sysjobs
```

will give you the list of all the jobs in the server while

```
select * from msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity
```

will give you the job activity details.

Comment: i want to view the script of the specific job ?